# Can't get these scripts to work together

Tags: javascript, html, css, compilation

I'm a second year application developer student doing an internship at an IT company, and my supervisor asked me to make a dropdown menu that looks and functions exactly like the one found on http://www.veermanict.nl/ at the top when in Mobile mode (you have to resize your window to mobile resolution to see what I'm talking about).

I am a total rookie and I've been struggling with this for two days. JavaScript hasn't even been covered in my education so I'm basically winging everything here, Googling for knowledge. I found a template I can alter in CSS to make it look more like what my supervisor wants, but the problem is that I can't seem to make it work.

I'm talking about this script: http://codepen.io/pedronauck/pen/fcaDw

I tried making an HTML document and linking the CSS and JavaScript to the HTML page like this:

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Menu Test 2</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="dropdown.js"></script>
</head>
```

... But it will simply show up as: prntscr (dot) com/8dxk4s (I'm not allowed multiple links, sorry)

So that means the CSS does work. But the Javascript doesn't? There are also errors inside of the CSS in Dreamweaver, as far as I can see. And isn't the JavaScript missing a semicolon at rule 25?

Please help me out. I don't want my supervisor to think I'm useless. But I'm stuck on this and he's too busy to help me out. I've tried a dozen of other options but he doesn't settle for mediocre.

Comment: Unless I've missed it you don't appear to have posted the script you're having trouble with (dropdown.js?).

Comment: you should load the `jquery` in the end of the `body` tag

Comment: I don't think that matters. The position of scripts should be in one place as I've learned. It can't be a flow error I think. None of this really helps me.

Comment: @SamHH look at the codepen link. The dropdown Javascript is in the box on the right.

Comment: does your `js` files are in same page or you have in another folder.If you have in another folder than you have to give the path for that

Comment: Firstly, @Amitsingh is correct about the script placement, however that's probably not the cause of your issues here. Secondly, that script is what you're trying to use. Have you straight copied it or have you altered it in any way?

Comment: @Amitsingh they are in the same folder. Everything is in the same root folder.

Comment: @SamHH I copied everything, then added the links to connect the script and the CSS to my HTML file like I posted in the code snippet. I tried without editing anything first to see if it worked like it did in the example on the Codepen website. that didn't work, I tried fixing the errors Dreamweaver gave me during this process (Missing semicolon, no "use strict";) etc, but still no dice.

Comment: This will be a lot easier to debug if you provider your own Codepen with entirely your own code. It's possible for example that Dreamweaver has fiddled with something it shouldn't have. (On that note, try to get away from using Dreamweaver.)

Comment: @SamHH I agree, I'd much rather use SublimeText or Notepad++ or even Netbeans, but my supervisor requires me to work with Dreamweaver sadly. I'll make my own codepen for you, give me a minute.

Comment: @SamHH here you go. It doesnt seem to work in Codepen either. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epNGyv

Comment: Check my answer, think I figured it out.

Comment: Please help me. I'm still stuck and I'm getting desperate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted `CSS` from `SCSS`
Use this css

**CSS**

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900");
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
body {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
  border-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.container > ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-weight: norma;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background: #2980B9;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
  background: #2c89c6;
}

.dropdown .icon-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  color: #fff;
  top: 14px;
  right: 10px;
}

.dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
  content: '\25BC';
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6e6e6e;
  background: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

.dropdown .show, .dropdown .hide {
  transform-origin: 50%, 0%;
}

.dropdown .show {
  display: block;
  max-height: 9999px;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.dropdown .hide {
  max-height: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

@keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0.1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.04);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleY(0.98);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.02);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but I still get the same results as before. Still looks the same as prntscr.com/8dxk4s

Answer (score 1):

You're using SCSS (Sass) code as if it's raw CSS. In the Codepen you provided it begins working immediately by changing CSS to SCSS.

Comment: Sorry for coming across as a rookie but I've never even heard of SCSS. Is it possible to convert it to regular CSS3? Or do I have to learn SCSS?

Comment: @Amitsingh I tried this but it gives me this error: 'file to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3
Current dir:  on line 2 at column 9'

Comment: It meas You have to import the `css` file of `compass` see the lie no 2 `@import compass/css3;` which you should download to use the style of compass

Comment: Oh.... I don't really know what you mean by that... I should put @import compass/css to line 2? Sorry for coming across as dumb I've never ever worked with this kind of code before and it's all coming at me in bulk now. My brain needs to process this...

Comment: @Reallyloudgirl check my answer that is converted `css` of `scss` file

Comment: I did. Thank you for trying to help, but sadly I still get the same results as before. The problem might be the Javascript.

Comment: In the Codepen you provided it works immediately by using the SCSS. It's a (S)CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

The language property for the script tag is deprecated. Use type, not both. Or just not use it at all. The default value is for type is text/javascript on all modern web browsers.

Comment: But that doesn't fix my problem. That's just a bit of redundancy/precaution for people using old/obscure browsers I guess, but it's not the thing breaking my code.

Comment: Well, did you try it?

Comment: I did, no dice, sorry.

Comment: Is this the script you're using for dropdown? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js